# Export Dataset having mutiple dataTable to a single sheet in excel

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, webforms, dataset

I have a DataSet having two DataTables. I want to export those DataTables one after the other in a single sheet in Excel(2013-xlsx).

As of now i have the code below that export the DataTables in separate sheet.Can you suggest any modification for this need?

```
 private void ExportDSToExcel(DataSet ds, string destination)
        {
            using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destination, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();
                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();

                uint sheetId = 1;

                foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                {
                    var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                    var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
                    sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
                    string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

                    if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
                    {
                        sheetId =
                            sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
                    }

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
                    sheets.Append(sheet);

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

                    List<String> columns = new List<string>();
                    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                    {
                        columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                        cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                        cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                        headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                    }

                    sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

                    foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
                    {
                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
                        foreach (String col in columns)
                        {
                            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                            cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                            newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                        }

                        sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: After inserting each data table, query the worksheet to see what the last row is, potentially add one or two for padding, and insert the next data table starting at that row.

Comment: The method seems to be cut off at the end...

Comment: @EricJ. Any code snippet that allow me to choose the column and row position?